# Combine two color schemes for coloring elements in matrix, based on their positions (i,j)

Tags: plotting, color

I want to color one of the diagonal elements of a matrix that consists of 45°  rotated and zigzag arranged squares. The addressing condition is following j=2*i and j=2*i-1, where j and i are the vertical and horizontal order numbers.

```
sideLength = 1;
rotatedSqare[x0_, y0_] := Polygon[{{x0, y0}, {x0 + sideLength*0.7, 
y0 - sideLength*0.7}, {x0 + sideLength*1.4, 
y0}, {x0 + sideLength*0.7, y0 + sideLength*0.7}}]
```

Applying the conditions individually If [j == 2*i , Blue, Green] and If [j == 2*i - 1 , Blue, Green] for coloring works properly, as shown below:

```
{Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.0013]], LightBlue, Table[{If [j == 2*i -    1 , Blue, Green], rotatedSqare[
  x0 + (period)*(i - 1) + Boole[OddQ[j + 1]]*(period)/2, 
  y0 + (period/2) j]}, {i, 1, 11}, {j, 1, 22}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 15}}, ImageSize -> 300], Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.0013]], LightBlue, Table[{If [j == 2*i , Blue, Green], rotatedSqare[
  x0 + (period)*(i - 1) + Boole[OddQ[j + 1]]*(period)/2, 
  y0 + (period/2) j]}, {i, 1, 11}, {j, 1, 22}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 15}}, ImageSize -> 300]}
```

[image]
[image]

When I combine two conditions together “ If [(j == 2*i And j == 2*i-1), Blue, Green]”, then I get this message:

> **“If is not a Graphics primitive or directive.”**

Can someone help me to get around this?
Thanks!!!

Comment: If you entered the same code as you gave in text, then you have probably a syntax error. You can replace that `And` with  `&&` or use `And` with infix notation as `If[(j == 2*i)~And~(j == 2*i - 1), Blue, Green]`.

Comment: You have also forgot to include the definitions for symbols `x0`, `y0` and `period` in your code. Please edit and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pint for repspondingi!!!

Comment: @Pinti. Thanks a lot Pint for repspondingi!!! Yes I forgot the parameters, here they are x0 = 0; y0 = 0; sideLength = 1; period = 1.5*sideLength.

Comment: @Pinti. I have tried both  If [(j == 2*i - 1) && (j == 2*i), Blue, Green] and  If [(j == 2*i - 1)~And~ (j == 2*i), Blue, Green]. It does not give any error message, but does not do apply the conditions.

Comment: @Pinti. I have tried both  If [(j == 2*i - 1) && (j == 2*i), Blue, Green] and  If [(j == 2*i - 1)~And~ (j == 2*i), Blue, Green]. This solves the e error message (it does not appear), and I get always the "false" result, it means all the pixels are green.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the missing parameters. That way it will be easier for other users to copy/paste the working code without searching in the comments. Also I do not understand what color pattern you are trying to achieve. Could you give us some small example or something?

Comment: @Pinti. THANKS a lot, it worked. actually I had to use Or insted of And.

Answer (score 1):

here is the result:

```
x0 = 0; y0 = 0;
sideLength = 1;
period = 1.5*sideLength;

rotatedSqare[x0_, y0_] := Polygon[{{x0, y0}, {x0 + sideLength*0.7, y0 - sideLength*0.7}, {x0 + sideLength*1.4, y0}, {x0 + sideLength*0.7, y0 + sideLength*0.7}}]

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.0013]], LightBlue, Table[{If [(j == 2*i - 1) || (j == 2*i), Blue, Green], rotatedSqare[
 x0 + (period)*(i - 1) + Boole[OddQ[j + 1]]*(period)/2, 
 y0 + (period/2) j]}, {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 22}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 15}}]
```

[image]